# How do I invoke a SLOT on expansion QTreeWidgetItem and not QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have my class in TaskGenJob.h where TaskGenModel inherits from QObject:-

## TaskGenJob.h

```
class TaskGenJob : public TaskGenModel    
{
    Q_OBJECT    
public:    
    TaskGenJob();    
    ~TaskGenJob();
}

TaskGenJob::TaskGenJob()
{    
//Connect signal itemExpanded to updateValue so that Display is updated only on tree expansion

connect(TaskGenJobDisplayPtr->getTaskGenJobTreeWdiget(), SIGNAL(itemExpanded(QTreeWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(updateValue()));    
}
```

In my TaskGenJob.cpp file, I try to connect QTreeWidgetItem's Signal to updateValue like the above.

But I get the following errors:-

```
/opt/qt_4.8.6/include/linux60_64/gcc48/QtCore/qobject.h:204:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QTreeWidgetItem*' to 'const QObject*'
/opt/qt_4.8.6/include/linux60_64/gcc48/QtCore/qobject.h:217:17: note: static bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, Qt::ConnectionType)
     static bool connect(const QObject *sender, const QMetaMethod &signal,
                 ^
/opt/qt_4.8.6/include/linux60_64/gcc48/QtCore/qobject.h:217:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QTreeWidgetItem*' to 'const QObject*'
/opt/qt_4.8.6/include/linux60_64/gcc48/QtCore/qobject.h:337:13: note: bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType) const
 inline bool QObject::connect(const QObject *asender, const char *asignal,
```

The errors are because QTreeWidgetItem doesn't inherit from `QObject` and doesn't have `SIGNAL(itemExpanded(QTreeWidgetItem*))`.
In my application's GUI I have 1 QTreeWideget and thousands of `QTreeWidgetItem` children. I have access to the pointers to these children. The requirement is that I must call the `SLOT updateValue` only on expansion of `QTreeWidgetItem` children.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, QTreeWidgetItem is not a subclass of Q object, nor does it have any signals. It is QTreeWidget that has these, so try connecting up it instead, in the same way as you are doing in the code snippet.

The QTreeWidget::itemExpanded signal is emitted when any of it's items are expanded and which one is expanded is  in it's argument.